# How to sort by a string date in ElasticSearch using ElasticSearch.js

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have a mapping with a field type of "text" that contains a date:

My mapping looks like this:

```
 "title" : "Nebula",
 "has_store" : true,
 "createdAt" : "Wed Nov 25 2020 05:37:08 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)",
```

How can I sort by this date `createdAt` to get the newest items first?

My query is using ElasticSearch.js

```
     bool: {
                must: [{
                    multi_match: {
                        query: data.searchTerm,
                        fields: [
                            "data.title^2.5",
                        ],
                        operator: "or",
                        lenient: "true",
                        type: 'best_fields',
                        fuzziness: "AUTO"
                    }
                }],

            }
        },
        from: Number(data.lastKey),
        size: Number(data.size)
    }
```

Is there a way to use scripts to do this? If so - how can I process the date into a real date object?

Or is there a way to sort by dates using the string format I have currently?

Answer (score 0):

It'd be best to reindex your fields as `dates` but if you *have to* sort by dates which are inside `text`, here's how you do it:

```
GET your_index/_search
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "type": "number",
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": """
            def df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z '('zzzz')'");
            return df.parse(doc['createdAt.keyword'].value).getTime();
          """
          
        },
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not familiar with the syntax for the "source" section and when trying in my code - it returns zero hits. What language/syntax is that code using for source? I have this in my code and it returns 0 hits `query.sort = [
    {
      _script: {
        type: "number",
        script: {
         lang: "painless",
          source: \`
            def df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z '('zzzz')'");
            return df.parse(doc['createdAt.keyword'].value).getTime();
          \`
        },
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]`

Comment: That would be the format of increased readability.. The sort should not affect the doc count though. So not sure why it's giving you 0 results.. Here's the compact form -- no need for the backtick quotes. `{"sort":[{"_script":{"type":"number","script":{"lang":"painless","source":"            def df = new SimpleDateFormat(\"EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z '('zzzz')'\");\n            return df.parse(doc['createdAt.keyword'].value).getTime();"},"order":"asc"}}]}`